# How to upload images or file added on fly using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Fill form details and click on add more button then form details are added on-the-fly in tabular format and are not actually stored anywhere. I need to insert in to database and upload selected images.

screenshot url:
http://www.orsatechnology.com/conv.jpg

Please help me to resolve it.

Code to generate grid

```
        //  To Generate conveyance Grid

$(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $('#addMore').click(function(){

            $('#dailyReportFrm').validate();  

            $('#gridDiv').show();

                var conNature       = $('#con_nature').val();
                var conNatureval    = $('#con_nature :selected').text();
                var noofKM          = $('#no_of_km').val();
                var perKMcost       = $('#cost_per_km').val();
                var noofDay         = $('#no_of_day').val();
                var bill            = $('#bill').val();
                var billAttach      = $('#bill_attach').val();
                var claimAmount     = $('#claim_amt').val();
                var empRemark       = $('#emp_remark').val();

                var str='';

                var id = i++;

        str ='<tr id="removeTR_'+i+'"><td>'+conNatureval+'<input type="hidden" id="con_nature_'+i+'" name="con_nature[]" value="'+conNature+'"><input type="hidden" id="no_of_km_'+i+'" name="no_of_km[]" value="'+noofKM+'"><input type="hidden" name="cost_per_km[]" id="cost_per_km_'+i+'" value="'+perKMcost+'"><input type="hidden" id="no_of_day_'+i+'" name="no_of_day[]" value="'+noofDay+'">'+bill+'<input type="hidden" id="bill_'+i+'" name="bill[]" value="'+bill+'"><input type="hidden" id="bill_attach_'+i+'" name="bill_attach[]" value="'+billAttach+'"></td><td>'+empRemark+'<input type="hidden" id="emp_remark_'+i+'" name="emp_remark[]" value="'+empRemark+'"></td><td>'+claimAmount+'<input type="hidden" id="claim_amt_'+i+'" name="claim_amt[]" value="'+claimAmount+'"></td><td align="center"><img class="delGridRow" onclick="delGridRow('+i+')" id="delConv_'+i+'" src="../../../public/images/delete_icon.png" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;" title="Click to Delete"></td></tr>';

            $('#convGrid').before("<tr></tr>",str);
            $("#convGrid").val('');

            $('#con_nature').val('');
            $('#no_of_km').val('');
            $('#cost_per_km').val('');
            $('#no_of_day').val('');
            $('#bill').val('');
            $('#bill_attach').val('');
            $('#claim_amt').val('');
            $('#emp_remark').val('');

            $("#KMDiv").hide();
            $('#expenseNatureBoarding').hide();
            $('#billAvailableDiv').hide();
            $('#billAttachDiv').hide();

        });

    });


    function delGridRow(id)
    {
        if(id!="")
        {
            var ans = confirm('Are you sure want to delete?');
            if(ans==true)
            {
                $('#removeTR_'+id).remove();

            /* if(id=='1')
                {
                    $('#gridDiv').hide();
                }*/

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }



HTML code
        <form name="dailyReportFrm" id="dailyReportFrm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                 <div id="conveyanceDiv">

                    <div style="overflow: auto;display:none;" id="gridDiv">
                        <table class="data display datatable" id="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nature of Expense</th>
                                <!-- th>Bill</th -->
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Remarks</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            </tr>
                                <tr class="odd gradeX" id="convGrid"></tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>



                <!-- ###################  Conveyance form start here ###################  -->

                 <div class="add-conveyance-heading_bg"><b>Fill Expense Details</b></div>

                 <div class="daily-report-form">
                 <div id="Conveyance-feild">
                <ul>

                <li id="natureOfExpenseDiv">
                <label>Nature of Expense <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="inputarea">
                <select name="con_nature[]" id="con_nature" class="required" title="Select a Nature of conveyance">
                <option value="">- Select -</option>    
                    <?php foreach($natureofconvArray as $cn=>$cnv): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $cnv['nature_id'];?>"> <?php echo $cnv['nature_name']; ?> </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select></div>                
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>


            <li id="KMDiv">
            <label>No. of KMs <span class="red">*</span></label>
            <div class="inputarea">
            <select name="no_of_km[]" id="no_of_km" class="required" title="Select no. of K.M.">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <?php for($km = 1; $km <= 500; $km++) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $km; ?>">  <?php echo $km; ?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Amount per KM &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs.<input type="text" name="cost_per_km[]" id="cost_per_km" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border:0px;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:4px;" readonly="readonly" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $perKMcost;?>" /> </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </li>








                <li id="expenseNatureBoarding" style="display:none;">
                <label>No. of Days <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="inputarea">
                <select name="no_of_day[]" id="no_of_day" class="required" title="Select no. of Day">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <?php for($day = 1; $day <= 20; $day++) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $day;?>"> <?php echo $day; ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>


                <li id="billAvailableDiv" style="display:none;">
                <label>Bill Available <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="inputarea">
                    <select name="bill[]" id="bill" class="required" title="Select bill availability">
                        <option value="">- Select -</option>
                        <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                        <option value="N">No</option>
                </select></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>

                 <li id="billAttachDiv" style="display:none;">
                <label>Attach</label>
                <div class="inputarea"><input type="file" name="bill_attach[]" id="bill_attach" /></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>


                 <li id="amountClaimDiv">
                <label>Amount Claimed <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="inputarea">
                    <input name="claim_amt[]" id="claim_amt" type="text" maxlength="5" readonly="readonly" class="text-box required number" title="Enter amount" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>

                 <li id="conveyanceRemarkDiv">
                <label>Remarks <span class="red">*</span></label>
                <div class="inputarea"><textarea name="emp_remark[]" id="emp_remark" cols="" rows=""></textarea></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>

                </ul>
                </div>

                <div  style="text-align:right; margin-top:10px;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl();?>/public/images/add-more-btn.jpg" alt="Add more" id="addMore" /></a></div>

                <p class="red" id="msg"><b>Note:</b> In case of 1st and Last Visit, Claimed Amt. will be 0.00 upto 20 km.</p>

                </div>
            </div>

                <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Save &amp; Next Visit" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Save &amp; Exit" />
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>

                 </form>
```

Comment: Please post your code and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Please visit [WhatHaveYoutried.com](http://www.WhatHaveYoutried.com).